# Write name in source code

Tags: html

How would I go about writing my name in code such as on this video he does it with react: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc

Comment: This is called ASCII art. There are specialized editors for it but a good text editor and a nonproportional font are enough.

Comment: You can create one [here](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're referring to the "untitled" file he has loaded into atom.

There are simply websites that do this for you (statically):
[examples](http://bfy.tw/5eje)

You can also use the command line tool `figlet`, which I'm sure you can use from server side. Create/Download fonts fairly easily.

Further more there are projects like [asciimo](https://github.com/Marak/asciimo) that do more or less everything you want in js